# Html Select "size" issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-select, microsoft-edge

The `select` element shown here (with a fixed width) has 3 options in it and a `size` of 3. So it should fit the content exactly.  However, it seems to reserve enough space at the bottom to be able to show all the `option` elements with the same height which it doesn't need to. (Run the code snippet to see.)

Is there any way to fix this, so that there is no extra space after the last `option`?

```css
.myClass select 
{
    width: 150px;
}

.myClass option{
   white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <select name="mySelect" size="3">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2 This options is very long so we wrap the text. That causes the select to show extra blank space at the bottom!</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Edit**

From the comments, it seems that browsers vary in how they display this.

Comment: I'm really confused what you're asking here. You say it has a size of 3 but it clearly says 4, and your filler text says you wrap it but you aren't.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It's wrapping for me?  What browser are you using? (I'm using Chrome 80.0.3987.132)

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica Firefox. I just opened it in Chrome and now I see what you're saying in your other comment, so it looks like it's a browser issue.

Comment: The size="4" was from a draft version of the question. Corrected now to show "3". The point is the extra space showing after the options.

Comment: Have added an Chrome bug at: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1060240

Comment: I tested and it can work well in Edge Legacy but has the same issue in Edge Chromium. I think the reason is as comment 4 in your issue report: *The intrinsic height is computed as maximum-option-height * 3.* And they won't fix this as it's the expected behavior. If you don't want the extra space, I think you can only give a fixed height to the `<select>`.

Comment: @yu-zhou My problem is that the contents of the list and its width can vary, so there's no easy way to set the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue won't be fixed by chromium team, you could use the below method as a workaround.

You can caculate the total height of the options then set it as the height of `<select>`:

```js
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
var opheight = 0;
for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  opheight += options[i].offsetHeight;
}
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].style.height = opheight + "px";
```

```css
.myClass select {
  width: 150px;
}

.myClass option {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <select name="mySelect" size="3" id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2 This options is very long so we wrap the text. That causes the select to show extra blank space at the bottom!</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, with minor extra padding.  (Works for Firefox too, but Firefox never wraps text, so it isn't needed.)